# How to determine which is the activity adapter in Windows?

Tags: windows, api, network-programming, adapter

I have multiple adapters just like default one, wifi-net, 3G card with usb etc in Windows.
How to determine which is the activity one? I tried to use GetAdaptersInfo/GetIfEntry but there is no answer. Could someone give me some suggest?

Comment: You can have multiple active, i.e. enabled, adapters. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm sorry for that, but Selbie got me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "activity one", so I'll assume you mean "which network adapter is the default for reaching the internet"?

Call [GetIpForwardTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365953%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Enumerate the [MIB_IPFORWARDROW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366850%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instances within the table.  The rows with the **`dwForwardDest`** member set to zero are the default routes.  In the event of more than one row with the `dwForwardDest` set to 0 (which can happen if you have more than one adpater), then use the `dwForwardMetric1` member as the tie-breaker (lowest value wins).

Once you find the default route row from `GetIpForwardTable`, you can use the `dwForwardIfIndex` member to identify which adapter in a call to [GetIfTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the default.

Comment: Thanks very much!!! Almighty overflow ah!! You got me and I wrote a little code with your suggest, I'm sure it works well. lol, tks guy again. I'll share the final result latter.